# Expose Methods in Properties as Single Class

Tags: c#, wcf, design-patterns

I needed to break up a WCF service contract that had a massive interface and clientbase class into smaller classes.  All of the smaller classes are similar but have different operation contracts.  I want to be able to expose the operation contract methods in all the new sub-classes as a single class for backwards compatibility.  Ideally it would look something like this:

```
public class MainClient {

    public MainClient() {
        Sub1 = new Sub1Client();
        Sub2 = new Sub2Client();
    }

    public static Sub1Client Sub1;
    public static Sub2Client Sub2;
}
```

I would then want to be able to call methods from `Sub1` and `Sub2` as if those methods were defined in `MainClient`.  So instead of calling `(new MainClient()).Sub1.Method1()` I would call `(new MainClient()).Method1()` where `Method1` still exists in the `Sub1Client` class.

Is this possible?

Comment: You should declare Method1 in MainClient, and inside the MainClient.Method1 is a call to the Sub1.Method1.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  Logistically though, it's a nightmare.  I'm looking at a god class that was 500K+ lines that needs to be broken up into at least 45 sub clients with ~2K operation contracts overall just to make xml serialization reasonably fast.  It's all regex and prayers from here on out.

Comment: Goodluck brother. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I not sure that clearly understand your question, but check this [solution](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rWWX8f):

```
public interface IFirst
{
    void Method1(string a);
}

public interface ISecond
{
    double Method2(int b, bool a);
}    

public interface IComplex : IFirst, ISecond
{
}

public class MyException : Exception
{
    public MyException(string message) : base(message)
    {
    }
}

public class Sub1Client : IFirst
{
    public void Method1(string a)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("IFirst.Method1");
        Console.WriteLine(a);
    }
}

public class Sub2Client : ISecond
{
    public double Method2(int b, bool a)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ISecond.Method2");
        return a ? b : -b;
    }
}

public class MainClient : IComplex
{
    public MainClient()
    {
        Sub1 = new Sub1Client();
        Sub2 = new Sub2Client();
    }

    public static Sub1Client Sub1;
    public static Sub2Client Sub2;        

    private T FindAndInvoke<T>(string methodName, params object[] args)
    {
        foreach(var field in this.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static))
        {
            var method = field.FieldType.GetMethod(methodName);
            if(method != null)
                return (T)method.Invoke(field.GetValue(this), args);
        }
        throw new MyException("Method was not found!");
    }

    public void Method1(string a)
    {            
        FindAndInvoke<object>(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, a);            
    }

    public double Method2(int b, bool a)
    {
        return FindAndInvoke<double>(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, b, a);
    }
}    

public static void Main()
{
    var test = new MainClient();
    test.Method1("test");
    Console.WriteLine(test.Method2(2, true));
}
```